# StartService method is executed but events of Service not fires

Tags: android, xamarin, service

I have an activity which I start a service in the OnCreate method. `StartService` method is executed without any error, but none of the events in Service class are not fired!
I test both of the explicit and implicit modes to start the service as you can see in my code, but both results were same!
My codes:

Activity:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try
    {
        serviceToStart = new Intent(ApplicationContext, typeof(TrackService));
        StartService(serviceToStart);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        var ee = e;
    }
}
```

Track Service:

```
[Service(IsolatedProcess = true, enabled = true)]
public class TrackService : Service
{
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;

    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        base.OnCreate(); //Break point set here
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Android.Content.Intent
                 intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        fusedLocationProviderClient = 
            LocationServices
            .GetFusedLocationProviderClient(this); //Break point set here
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }

    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Manifest:

**EDIT**: Manifest manuals removed removed

Can anyone say me what's the problem?

Comment: @SushiHangover I did it, The only error which logcat shows is: `No implementation found for void mono.android.Runtime.register`. Is this related to service starting?

Comment: Not in Oncreate and StartCommandResult

Comment: Yes, I did it. But no result. I think there are some problems in my package name. I've moved mobile part of package name from among of it to the beginning by refactoring. I think it may cause some problems

Comment: When I use implicit calling service start, the mono error disappears. However, I'm testing with all possible forms of the methods in my code

Answer (score 0):

Please mention you service in the manifest file. This is very important step because without manifest service entry your service class never initiated.

Below line of code is very important, this should be in your manifest file.

```
<service android:name=".TrackService" android:enabled="true"></service>
```

Referrer to below link for more clarification about the services
 - https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service

Comment: This is `Xamarin.Android` based and the Service attribute on the service subclass will automatically add the manifest entry during the build process

Comment: My code is in Xamarin and this manifest is Java android style. In Xamarin it's enough to declare manifest as the attribute in intent classes.

Comment: Sorry I don't have much knowledge of Xamarin.Android but In native android java/kotlin project this is mandatory to mention service name in the manifest manually.

Answer (score 0):

1) Allow the `ServiceAttribute` (and the build process) to property set the manifest entry and no manual changes are needed:

```
[Service(IsolatedProcess = true, enabled = true)]
```

Note: If you wish/need to manually change the manifest, you will need to assign the `Name` in the ServiceAttribute to hard-code a fully-qualified package and Java class name that you can then use in your manifest

2) When starting the service, build an intent using the application context and the C# type of your service:

```
var serviceIntent = new Intent(ApplicationContext, typeof(TrackService));
StartService(serviceIntent);
```

Comment: I've changed all as simple as you said. But the breakpoints (OnCreate and OnStartCommand never work!). All things seem correct but I don't know where is the problem. I made a new pure project and put this two code in it. But I don't get the result yet! :(

Answer (score 0):

Finally! I found the problem root! However, I don't know why it happens and how can I resolve it!

I always got this error in logcat:

> No implementation found for void mono.android.Runtime.register

After removing part by part of the code I got that the problem is caused by `IsolatedProcess` attribute. Just by removing it the code works well.

**Note:** As you can see there's no need to put `enabled` attribute for service too.

```
[Service]
public class TrackService : Service
```